# How to customize a ui item, and apply that to all viewcontrollers?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uikit, iboutlet

I have a UITextField, that I had customized in my firstViewController. 
Now I wan't it to have the same behavior on the other ViewControllers.
Is there anyway to import all the properties on a IBOutlet?

Comment: did you customize it by code or by xib?

Comment: I've cotumized by code :) 

Basiclly i've some methods applied to it for search proposes, and a costum background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple create your own Customclass and set the property in the constructor.

```
@interface CustomTextField : UITextField

@end


@implementation CustomTextField

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
      //Customize here
      self.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault;
      self.text = @"Blub";
      ....
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

if your create a new Textfield, create the object with your custom class:

```
CustomTextField *field = [[CustomTextField alloc] initWithFrame: ...];
```

Comment: awesome. Tks a lot for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define a base view controller, then derive all of your view controllers from it?

```
@interface MyBaseCustomViewController : UIViewController
 ...
@property(...) UITextField* ...
 ...
@end

@interface MyOtherCustomViewController : MyBaseCustomViewController
 ...
```

Comment: Humm you mean like a template? It seems awsome. I'm fresh to ios, so i'm still digging on it.

Comment: actually, it's not a template, just a base class. possibly, it could help if you post your code and an example of what you would like to attain...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could make a subclass of UITextField, this subclass will have the all the custom code that you did in the viewcontroller as a function in your subclass.

For example

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    //UITextField *textField;
    //change color, background, size etc..
}
```

Now create a new class called UICustomTextField that derives from UITextField
in this class create a method:

```
//in UICustomTextField.m
- (void) doCustomModifications
{
    self.stuff = custom stuff;
    other custom stuff
    etc...
}
```

Call doCustomModifications in your code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [customTextField doCustomModifications];
}
```